# How to save an empty array property with Neo4jclient

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm using a neo4jclient and one of my data classes has a `Collection<string>` property.

On save, I got the following error:

> "Unable to set property 'SomeArrayPropertyName' to an empty array, because, since there
>   are no values of any type in it, and no pre-existing collection to
>   infer type from, it is not possible to determine what type of array to
>   store."

Is there a way to save an empty array without changing it to Null ?

Edit:

Example:

```
public class BaseData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    public Collection<string> Subjects { get; set; }

    public BaseData()
    {
        Subjects = new Collection<string>();
    }

    //This method lets Json.Net know whether to serialize 'Subjects'
    public virtual bool ShouldSerializeSubjects()
    {
        return Subjects != null && Subjects.Any();
    }
}

public class ParentData : BaseData
{
}

public class ChildData : ParentData 
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4jclient uses Json.net to parse the data classes, so you *can* add a method to your Data class which Json.net will look for, in the format `ShouldSerializePROPERTYNAME` (see the example below).

```
public class Actor
{
    public string Name { get;set;}
    public Collection<string> Alternatives { get;set; }

    //This method lets Json.Net know whether to serialize 'Alternatives'
    public bool ShouldSerializeAlternatives()
    {
        return Alternatives != null && Alternatives.Any();
    }
}
```

This will serialize `new Actor{Name = "Jeff", Alternatives=new Collection<string>()}` as: `{"Name":"Jeff"}` - no `Alternatives` at all.

Obviously the downside here is that your class when deserialised will have a null collection - which you might be ok with, or not - if not - you could just stick an initializer in the constructor:

```
public Actor() { Alternatives = new Collection<string>(); }
```

which will be called when Json.Net deserializes the object.

There is another way using an [IContractResolver](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConditionalProperties.htm) but if you have access to the data classes, the above way is easiest.

There is no way to get around the empty collection other than not serialize it, as neo4j won't allow you to send the data in.

--EDIT--

```
public class BaseData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Collection<string>  Subjects { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeSubjects()
    {
        return Subjects != null && Subjects.Any();
    }

    public BaseData()
    {
        Subjects = new Collection<string>();
    }
}

public class ParentData :BaseData {}

public class ChildData : ParentData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost.:7474/db/data/"));
        client.Connect();

        var cd = new ChildData { Name = "c1", Description = "des", Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
        var nodeRef = client.Create(cd);
        var cdRetrieved = client.Get<ChildData>(nodeRef);

        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Description: {1}, Id: {2}, Subjects: {3}", cd.Name, cd.Description, cd.Id, cd.Subjects.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Description: {1}, Id: {2}, Subjects: {3}", cdRetrieved.Data.Name, cdRetrieved.Data.Description, cdRetrieved.Data.Id, cdRetrieved.Data.Subjects.Count);

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cd);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

Gives the following output:

```
Name: c1, Description: des, Id: ff21b0fe-0a51-4269-a1d4-e148c905a6d7, Subjects: 0
Name: c1, Description: des, Id: ff21b0fe-0a51-4269-a1d4-e148c905a6d7, Subjects: 0
{"Name":"c1","Description":"des","Id":"ff21b0fe-0a51-4269-a1d4-e148c905a6d7"}
```

The last line is the actual JSON output by Json.Net, with no 'subjects' serialized.

Comment: It's not working... The `ShouldSerializeAlternatives` method is in the base class. could that be the problem?

Comment: It's seems like the problem is because of the inheritance. Anything I can do about that?

Comment: It needs to be in the same class as the collection, if it's in the base / derived class doesn't matter as long as it's the same as the collection...

Comment: Thank you but it's in the same class and it's not working. Is it possible that I have to mark something with some attribute?

Comment: Can you add your class code to the question? I've experimented with a variety of inheritance situations, and so far the only time the ShouldSerializeXXX method was ignored was when it wasn't in the same class as the implementation...

Comment: If you remove the `virtual` bit from the ShouldSerializeXXX method, it will work.. You don't need it to be virtual.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a full program (which you will be able to stick into a Console app once you've added nuget for Neo4jclient) which works and stores the objects in the DB, and gets them back out. I hope that clears up anything.

Comment: Thank you. This example helped to locate my error. problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Pasted from [Neo4j doco](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-property-values.html):

> Storing empty arrays is only possible given certain preconditions. Because the JSON transfer format does not contain type information for arrays, type is inferred from the values in the array. If the array is empty, the Neo4j Server cannot determine the type. In these cases, it will check if an array is already stored for the given property, and will use the stored arrays type when storing the empty array. If no array exists already, the server will reject the request.

This implies providing empty array works when updating existing array for which array type is already known by Neo4j. New array property cannot be empty.